# inserting the date into table

Tags: oracle, date

> ORA-01843: not a valid month ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
    empno NUMBER,
    empname VARCHAR2(255), 
    DOB DATE,
    salary NUMBER, 
    designation VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO emp VALUES(100,'John','4.21.1994', 50000,'Manager');
```

error while trying to insert data into table

Answer (score 0):

Two changes you should make to your insert statement are:

- Specify all the target columns after the table name, and
- Use a valid ANSI date literal for the date

```sql
INSERT INTO emp (empno, empname, DOB, salary, designation)
VALUES
    (100, 'John', date '1994-04-21', 50000, 'Manager');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're (wrongly) relying on implicit data conversion (from string to `date`), but - Oracle failed in guessing what you wanted to do, and you failed in providing format which would be recognized by Oracle.

There are several options you can use; pick the one you find the most appropriate, as long as it is valid.

```
SQL> desc temp
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMPNAME                                            VARCHAR2(255)
 DOB                                                DATE
```

---

Use date literal, which always has the `date` keyword followed by date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format:

```
SQL> insert into temp (empname, dob) values ('John', date '1994-04-21');

1 row created.
```

---

Use `to_date` function whose format model follows value you entered:

```
SQL> insert into temp (empname, dob) values ('Jim' , to_date('4.21.1994', 'mm.dd.yyyy'));

1 row created.
```

---

If you choose to use month names, beware of different languages!

```
SQL> insert into temp (empname, dob)
  2  values ('Mike', to_date('apr.21.1994', 'mon.dd.yyyy', 'nls_date_language=english'));

1 row created.
```

---

If you alter session and set any format model and date language, you can insert a *string* in that format (but, once again, you shouldn't rely on implicit datatype conversion):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-dd-mon';

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.

SQL> insert into temp (empname, dob) values ('Jack', '1994-21-apr');

1 row created.

SQL>
```